# Python ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.') (error -3)

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

When I try to install the package pandas I get the following output:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', error('Error -3 while decompressing d
> ata: incorrect data check'))

I restart IDE PyCharm, python 3.7. The next step will be restart the whole PC...

Comment: how did you try to install it?

Comment: pip install pandas

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a corrupted pip cache. I fixed it by running

```
pip cache purge
```